# The permissions granted to user 'servername/iusr-username' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have tried everything that most forums have said and still cannot get other people in the network to see this report.

Here's the things I have tried:

1. in `servername/reports` under `properties` tab i have added my user `domain/username` and given him all 5 roles (*Browser*, *Content Manager*, *My Reports*, *Publisher*, *Report Builder*)
2. in the `site settings` --> `Configure Site wide security` --> `domain / username`, i have given *System Administrator* role.
3. In `IIS`, I have given both the `reports` and `reportserver` in `Directory Security` --> `Integrated Windows Authentication` and unchecked `Anonymous Access`.

Even after this I am the only one who can view this report. Whenever another user on the domain tries to access it, the login dialog pops up and they need my password to get in.

All I need is that whenever any user types `servername/reportserver` in his IE, the report should pop up without any login requirements.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You need to go into your **[SSRS ReportManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx)** and configure the security settings.

Through `Properties -> Security -> New Role Assignment->` Then add the appropiate domain group. If all users need access, then use "YourDomain\Domain Users".

Comment: so you are saying i add all users individually? domain/username1, domain/username2 ? I have like 300 people here who shall be looking at this

Comment: You can add the group "Domain Users" which includes all users

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the servername\iusr_servername has at least select rights to your database (or execute for a stored proc). If you are going the anonymous route.

As general rule though I try to stay with the default security configuration as much as possible. I've spent way to much time fiddling with IIS and RS user configuration etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can the other people even see your computer and database? So often these kinds of problems are simple network / OS authentication problems.