# The permissions granted to user 'DOMAIN\MY-DESK$' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

My desktop name is `DOMAIN\MY-DESK`. So the error is regard as to my desktop rather than my Windows credential.

I searched the web most of them are related to `DOMAIN\UserName` issue. The local report url is `http://localhost/WebAdminOrion/Administrative/Reports`

The report page is in a asp.net web application. I have the following code in the report page.

```
 ReportParameter[] prm = new ReportParameter[Request.QueryString.Keys.Count - 1];
 ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(prm);
```

I get the error at the line of setting parameters.
  By [this,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155866(v=sql.120).aspx) I think that the solution might be to configure the file. However the file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config` has 292 lines. One section is

```
<Authentication>
<AuthenticationTypes>
  <RSWindowsNTLM />
</AuthenticationTypes>
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
<EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
```

Not sure how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it and shamed. [The permissions granted to user 'servername/iusr-username' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977555/the-permissions-granted-to-user-servername-iusr-username-are-insufficient-for)

You need to go into your SSRS ReportManager and configure the security settings.

Through Properties
 -> Security -> New Role Assignment-> Then add the appropriate domain group. For my case, it needs to add by desk name as "DOMAIN\DESK$".